# load asp.net page from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect, refresh

I have a asp.net project.

On one of the pages i have a table that gets filled when the page gets loaded, every row has a delete button, when its clicked it deletes that row from the server and refreshes the page. i do this with a

> WebMethod

That the javascript on call back redirects to that page using:

```
window.location.href = "HomePage.aspx";
```

The problem is that it doesnt really load the page again but it just refreshes it, that way the table displayed on the page still has the row that was deleted, even when it was really deleted.

I fill the table in the HomePage.aspx page like this:

```
<table id="pipesTbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Current Status</th>
                    <th>Last run summary</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <%
                foreach (var name in Names)
               {%>
               <tr>
                    <td><% Response.Write(name.age);%><br /</td>
                    <td><% Response.Write(name.age);%><br />2 hours and 22 minutes...</td>
                    <td>Good<br />01/07/2011</td>

                </tr>                     
                <%}  %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Any idea what i can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work

```
location.reload(true);
```

this is what the documentation says

> reload(forceget) Reload the document from the current URL. forceget is a boolean, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

**EDIT (comment that held solution):** 
In case you are in a asp.net webforms project put this in the page load. If you are in an MVC project I think it must be in the controller (not sure)

c# version (for vb.net see comments):

```
 Random rd = new Random();
 Response.AddHeader("ETag", rd.Next(1111111, 9999999).toString());
 Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
 Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
 Response.Expires = -1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt do the trick... The table will only load correctly again after i logout and log back in to the page... i dont know why he does that...

Comment: In my opinion this can only be a cache or a database problem. Try searching in those directions. This code (in VB.NET) might help `Dim rd As New Random() Response.AddHeader("ETag", rd.Next(1111111, 9999999).ToString()) Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache") Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" Response.Cache.SetNoStore() Response.Expires = -1`

Comment: its probably a cache issue. how do i use the above code? were to put it? can you please give it to me in c#? Thankyou

Comment: In case you are in a asp.net webforms project put this in the page load. If you are in an MVC project I think it must be in the controller (not sure) c# translation:  `Random rd = new Random(); Respone.AddHeader("ETag", rd.Next(1111111, 9999999).toString()); Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"; Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); Response.Expires = -1;` (It's been a while I've done c# so check the code first:) ).

Comment: Wooow, it worked........... Thank you very very much! Maybe edit your answer with this thing you added, for Future use..

Comment: I made a mistake... i had something in my code (a workaround) that fixed my prob, and i forgot it was there, and then when i added you code it obviously worked, but now i see it really didnt do it...:(, sorry for driving you crazy...